# Compare two date properties of a list

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-entities

I have two lists:

```
List<DateTime> monthWorkingDays

List<Note> monthUserNotes
```

In my Note class i have a **DateTime NoteDate** property (represents the date of note).

I need to check if the user didnt make any note in a working day to send a email to that user.

So i have to compare the **NoteDate** property with the **monthWorkingDays** data.

```
 public List<DateTime> GetIncompleteDays()
    {
        var days = GetWorkingDays();
        var incompleteDays = new List<DateTime>();
        var notes = GetLast30DaysNotesByUser(idUser).OrderBy(a => a.NoteDate);

            foreach (var note in notes)
            {
                //TODO
            }

        return incompleteDays;
    }
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You need a double for loop.  If you can compare ( >, <) note dates, then you can break out of the inner loop earlier (and definitely break if you have a match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not sort notes by date - sort selected incomplete days instead:

```
days.Select(d => d.Date)
    .Except(notes.Select(n => n.NoteDate))
    .OrderBy(d => d)
```

As Tim stated, you may not need to select `d => d.Date` if days do not have Time part. Consider to introduce some explanatory variables, to make solution more clear:

```
var workingDays = GetWorkingDays();
var notes = GetLast30DaysNotesByUser(idUser);
var daysWithNotes = notes.Select(n => n.NoteDate).Distinct();
var incompleteDays = workingDays.Except(daysWithNotes);
```

Comment: I have just the Date part for the NoteDate property. I keep the time in other property called only Date(represents the moment that the user made the Note in the system)

Comment: @ggui ah, ok, I'll update answer to make it more clear. Btw I think `GetLastMonthNotesOfUser(userId)` is a better name for method. Also if your `GetWoringDays()` method returns working days of last month, it's better to name it `GetLastMonthWorkingDays()`

Comment: you´re right the name is ugly. But it cant be last month because it isnt the last month, it is the last 30 days actually. But ill change it anyway. Thanks

Comment: @ggui well, requirement looks strange to me - usually such reports done on month basis, but there are months where 31 or 28 days

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `DateTime`s are comparable (if there is a time portion, you can remove that with the [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property), this should work, using LINQ's [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var incompleteDays = days.Except(
         GetLast30DaysNotesByUser(idUser).Select(a => a.NoteDate));
```

Comment: Amazing, i was trying to make loops and getting crazy about that.Forgot this Except method in LINQ!